# How to read my website user (not google user) tracking id from google analytics tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Instead of using google analytics `User ID` feature I want to read User Id which `ga.js` automatically generates and stores in browser cookies. I want to read this id so I can send it to my server. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think you can read cross-domain cookies. I assume that's what you're trying to do? :)

Comment: oh, you right. Anyway I prefer API for this to avoid any side effects

Comment: This limitation would not apply to analytics scripts hosted on the same domain. Have you considered something like http://piwik.org?

Comment: No. I should do this with Google Analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the client ID that analytics.js stores in cookies as follows:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
});
```

Here's the page in the documentation that describes how:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId

Note: the `clientId` is different from the [`userId`](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en)

#### Update:

keep in mind that any time the user clears their cookies, the client ID will change. Do not use it to identify particular users.